# mobilefirst push notifications for windows phone doesnt function

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst

Hello im trying to send  a windows phone 8 push notification that is working in ios and android environment, but in my windows phone cell doesnt recieve.

In my worklightconsole  ive seen that the user is suscribe and the push is send.

this is my custom configuration for windows phone environment

application-descriptor.xml:

```
<windowsPhone8 version="1.0" securityTest="xxxxxxxxxx-strong-mobile-securityTest">
        <uuid>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</uuid>
        <pushSender />
</windowsPhone8>
```

WL adapter code:

```
try {
        var usuario = "9136";
        var usuariosNoEncontrados = 0;
        // var cantUsuarios = usuarios.length
                try {
            var badgeDigit = 1;

            var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(mensaje, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});
             notification.MPNS.raw = {
                        payload : {payload : "You have a meeting in 5 minutes"}
                    };
            var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription(
                    'Fiesta2015_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS.FiestaEventSource', usuario);
            if (userSubscription != null) {
                WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);
            } else {
                WL.Logger
                        .info("User not found:: "
                                + usuario);
            }

            return {
                codigo : "0",
                error : "",
                respuesta : "OK"
            };

        } catch (e) {
            return {
                codigo : "2",
                error : e,
                respuesta : ""
            };
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return {
            codigo : "2",
            error : e,
            respuesta : ""
        };
    }
```

trace in my developer server

```
[10/2/15 15:04:52:732 GMT-03:00] 0000040a com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.mpns.MPNSSender        E FPWSE1028E: Notification through Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS) to subscription 'http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/bn1/H2QAAACeRdLTzN62GukR6VNR79CH16nLA287g3zW2jmMAKEM7yA2YQcWSrJJbBBd7ma0MjJqB4Za0hceofRW258O2kqxVikHilukxiiThqkCI6JNGeXldHH2RZPutOv_qL2EM94/JHtzZXJ2aWNlbmFtZX0/Y6WgLTaz-ESHoQtbNpQ2HQ/S7AyIDdrf4nCanHvc95MA4wyO90' was not delivered (reason: 's.notify.live.net')
java.net.UnknownHostException: s.notify.live.net
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.mpns.MPNSSender.sendAndVerify(MPNSSender.java:241)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.mpns.MPNSMediator.sendOrWait(MPNSMediator.java:88)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.mpns.MPNSMediator.sendNotification(MPNSMediator.java:80)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Mediator$2.run(Mediator.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Which configuration im missing.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Define "not working".

Comment: ive just add some logs to the post

Comment: 1)Any error messages in server side when push is dispatched?
2) What is the client side code to handle the notification? Post the client side code that handles incoming notifications?
3) Was the application in foreground or background when you tried the push notification. Raw notification works only when the application is in foreground.

Comment: 1) no logs in the server , neither info or error (the error trace that i put was from my messages.log but was because i was connected with a vpn)
2)the push comes when im ni foreground (ive pop an alert) 
3) i trying to see my push in when my app is in background

Answer (score 1):

When application is in background only toast and tile notifications are applicable on Windows Phone 8.

a) To get Toast notifications , modify the adapter code:

```
notification.MPNS={};   
notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});

//Set Toast notification for MPNS
notification.MPNS.toast={};
notification.MPNS.toast.text1 = "Toast title";
notification.MPNS.toast.text2 = "Toast content";
```

b) For tile notifications, pin the application to the start screen.